# requirejs path mapping for prefixed script files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Tried googling to my hearts content on this one, and trawling through the API documentation on requirejs to no avail.

Is it possible to specify a path prefix for requirejs to use, based on the prefix of the script files/Module's I'll be using?

I want to prefix all calls to "kendo.xxxModuleNamexxx.min.js" with "kendo/kend.xxxModuleNamexxx.min.js" - For sake of keeping my solution nice and tidy and not having a gigantic scripts folder :)

Structure:

- ***index***

  - scripts
  - jquery.min.js
  - isotope.min.js
  - knockout.min.js
  - someothermodules.js
  - requirejs.js
  - main.js
  - ***kendo***

    - kendo.web.min.js
    - kendo.combobox.min.js
    - kendo.fx.min.js

FYI - All kendo scripts are AMD compatible and report their module Id's as prefixed: kendo.moduleName..... etc.

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately, due to number of other scripts in my directory, I still require my baseUrl to be the "/scripts" folder. (The number of kendo scripts is so many that's why I'm after a separate base folder for those prefixed scripts)

Thanks in advance :)

James

Comment: Did you try requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '[Your base url]',
})?

Comment: Yep, sorry my question probably wasn't clear, I still want my baseUrl to map to the "scripts" directory... I'll update the question. Thanks though - Any other ideas? :)

Comment: Have you tried to replace the filename by a function which will return the new path ?

Comment: @Antoine where would I replace the filename/would I need to do that for all module Ids? I'd rather have a more generic solution if possible so that I don't need to maintain individual files/folders going forward

Comment: Yeah, it would require to do it for all the files.
Another idea: replace the whole kendo inclusion section by something like this: (function() { .... })(), so it will be executed at runtime.
And inside you can read the directory where all your files are included, create a hash, and return it to requirejs.
I'm not sure it's clear enought, if it's not could you put your current requirejs code, I'll edit it with what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You might write your own *normalization plugin* that coordinates resource name and loads "kendo" scripts instead. Unfortunately I don't know if there is a way to load plugins without prefix. So you need to prefix all dependencies with `kendo!`.

```js
//see https://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html

define('kendo', (require, exports, module) => {
    return {
        normalize: function (name, normalize) {
            return 'kendo/' + name
        },
        load: function (name, req, onload, config) {           
            req([name], function (value) {
                onload(value);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Usage:

`require(['kendo!a.js', 'kendo!b.js'], (a, b) => { return ... }`